# conflicto entre jquery ui y jequery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo un sistema y partes de el codigo que usa jquery ui no funcionan junto a jquery. Como puedo evitar ese conflicto, las partes de jquery que me esta dando problema es en unas ventanas modal que muestra un formulario para editar datos.
Al hacer la llamada

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_categ('."'".$categ->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
```

no carga el modal, si quito el jquery ui si carga, pero necesito el jquery ui para otras partes donde hago autocompletar y otros modal tambien.

Comment: Podrías incluír el código de la función `edit_categ`, normalmente las librerías de jQuery no tienen conflictos entre ellas, a menos que sea por versiones antiguas que estés usando de una o ambas librerías

Answer (score 0):

Si claro es

```
 function edit_categ(id)
 {
save_method = 'update';
$('#form')[0].reset(); 
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
$('.help-block').empty(); 


$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('categorias/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
        $('[name="nombre"]').val(data.nombre);
        $('[name="familia"]').val(data.familia);
        $('#modal_form').modal('show'); 
        $('.modal-title').text('Editar categoria'); 

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error ');
    }
});
```

}
estoy haciendolo con codeigniter.
las versiones que estoy usando son jquery ui v1.12.1 y jquery min v3.2.1